# Import SWF to FLA

Tags: actionscript, flash

I can show a swf into flash simply with this code

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myswf.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
loader.load(request);
addChild(loader);
```

But with import > import to stage there is no any swf when ctrl+enter.
There is only 5-6 empty frame in timeline. How can I solve this problem??

Another question, how can I do this with as 2.0 (im not familiar with as 2.0). This code not working :

```
loadMovie("myswf.swf");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Loader()** and **addChild()** are both AS3, so won't work in AS2.

**loadMovie()** is a movieClip method, so it needs a movieClip instance to operate on:

```
myMovieClip.loadMovie("myswf.swf");
```

To load your swf into the main timeline, try:

```
this.loadMovie("myswf.swf");
```

Comment: You're welcome - don't forget you can click the big tickmark to 'accept' an answer (this will encourage others to help you out in future!)